# What are some words or expressions which can be used to describe a wrong decision?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, sentence

What are some words/expressions with which we can describe the wrong decisions made in the past by a person/entity/organisation?

The sentence:

> Real Madrid claims to have the biggest fanbase in club football which brings doubt in mind, as some of the decisions made by the club have been wrong.

There are many perspectives from which a decision can be wrong. For example:

- The decision was wrong morally.
- The decision was wrong in the public eyes, socially and politically.
- The decision was wrong business-wise and economically.
- The decision was generally wrong in all senses

What possible word or expression could best describe all of the above perspectives?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you looking for something like *interpretation*? If so, what words have you already looked at but ruled out. Can you provide an example sentence that would use the word you're looking for?

Comment: You're not asking about the meaning of a word, or about the structure of a sentence. You're requesting a word. The tags `[meaning]` and `[sentence]` do not apply here, and there's a lot more you can do with satisfying [what's required for `[single-word-request]`](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for:

[**Blunder**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blunder)

> A gross, stupid, or careless mistake
>
> <sub>[Dictionary.com Unabridged
>
> Based on the Random House Unabridged Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2018]</sub>

Comment: Don't you think Blunder would be too harsh?

Comment: @RajatAudichya You have given no indication in your question of what sort of word you want. Please read the [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) (which is admittedly less easy to find now) and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question point by point:

You can describe a morally wrong decision by calling it immoral/unethical/improper

You can describe a social wrong decision  by calling it unrighteous/unethical/dishonest

You can describe an incorrect economic decision by calling it unwise/uninformed

You can describe a generally wrong decision by calling it bad/ill-advised/unfitting